# How do I set up test environment with git?

Tags: git

I need the best git setup practice for situations like this:

[image]

I am currently working on a Laravel project, let's call it `core` for now, which has two implementations (called `project_1`, `project_2`). The two implementations share the same `core`. The differences are the models, controllers, requests, routes, etc.

**First attempt**

I set 3 folders, one called `core`, one called `project_1`, one called `project_2`. The `core` only has the common files that shared in both projects. There are no models, controllers in `core`. Each time I make changes to core, I can easily push to either project. However, the problem is, since the `core` doesn't have any models, controllers..., I can't do any testings.

**Second attempt**

So later, I created a `test` project from `core`, with models, controllers copied from `project_2`. And add those files in `.git/info/exclude`, then `git rm --cached file` each of them. But problem is, when push or pull, those files are also deleted in `project_2`...

**What I want to achieve**

I would like a setup, that I can easily twist and test codes in `test` project, and then only push codes inside `core` to `project_1` and `project_2`.

Comment: I think it would make more sense if 1 and 2 pulled new changes from core. but that is a matter of preference I guess.

Comment: @TimCastelijns That's what I did in first attempt. The problem is I can't do testings. Since it is a bare core, without supporting files in real project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use branches.

A branch contains a separate history of changes, from a specific point in your repository's base branch; called **master**.

Checking out a branch; will switch your directory to only those files that are tracked in that branch.

There are many different branching strategies that you can find online. For example, [this article by atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) describes the feature branch workflow.

In your case, you should try something simple:

1. Create your repository.
2. Add only those files that are common to all environments. I am assuming this is the "core"; and commit your changes.
3. Create a branch for project 1, with `git checkout -b project_1`
4. You'll have all files from *core* added here
5. Work as normal, any files you create/add/edit will only tracked in the project_1 branch and will not affect the "core" (or master branch).

If you want to create a test environment, to test out whatever project 1 is doing:

1. Create a new branch called test_project_1, from the master branch.
2. Merge in the project_1 branch; with `git merge project_1`.
3. Do your testing.
4. If you find a bug; switch back to project_1; `git checkout project_1`.
5. Create a new branch for that bug fix, for example `git checkout -b project_1_bugfix_1`.
6. Fix the bug, once done; you can check it out and test on the test branch (`git checkout test_project_1; git merge test_project_1_bugfix_1`).
7. Once you confirm the bug is fixed, you should merge the changes back to the main `project_1` branch; with `git checkout -b project_1; git merge project_1_bugfix_1`.
8. Now if you want, you can delete the bugfix branch; with `git branch -d project_1_bugfix_1`.

Each time you switch branches; the file system will only reflect the files that are tracked in that branch (of course, any un-tracked files will be left as is).

---

> What if I found a bug in core while in test_project_1 branch? How
>   should I fix it? Should I fix it in test_project_1 branch?

1. Switch to the core (your master branch).
2. Create a branch to implement the bugfix.
3. Fix the issue.
4. Test it (the same way you would test any other branch).
5. Merge the bugfix branch back into the master.
6. Switch to `test_project_1`.
7. [Rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) from master.

Comment: What if I found a bug in core while in test_project_1 branch? How should I fix it? Should I fix it in test_project_1 branch? If so, how do I merge that fix back to core branch and then push to project_2 branch? Or should I go back to core branch and fix it? In that case, how do I do testing while trying to fix it?

Comment: So following your suggestion, after I fix something in bug_fix_core branch, I cannot test it right away in that branch. Instead, I have to merge that fix to test_core branch and then I can do some tests. Ideally, I'd prefer fix that bug in test branch and, if possible, merge that back to bug_fix branch. It'd be more convenient. But is there a way to do so?

Comment: Typically - once you make a fix in a branch - you first [a] test if the fix itself doesn't have any bugs [b] test if the fix didn't break anything else. Then once have done that, you consider the bug fixed and you can now you need to implement the fix into the core - so the next time someone branches off the core, they have that fix; keep in mind everything is based from core / master. **These are all my suggestions, you are free to do it however you see fits best in your scenario**.

Comment: I am sorry but I not arguing on the way you suggested. I was asking if there is way that I could do modifications in test branch (skips bug_fix branch, so that I don't have to merge to test branch before I can do test), and then merge back to master/core directly from test branch.

Comment: You can but it will be difficult to undo changes.